# Loading a 32 bit unsigned value into a single mips register

Tags: assembly, mips, unsigned, mips32, ci20

I am currently working a program that runs the Collatz Conjecture.
I am confused how to represent `2^32 - 1` or `0xFFFFFFFF` into a single register. I am currently using

```
#lui $s5, 0xFFFF  # 2^32 - 1 stored in $s5
#ori $s5, $s5, 0xFFFF # storing 0xFFFFFFF in $s5
li $s5, 0xFFFFFFFF # pseudo instruction of above
addu $s6, $0, $s5
```

To get the unsigned value of `0xFFFFFFFF` into register `$s6`. When I run the program through gdb debugger I am getting the 2's complement of `0xFFFFFFFF` `-1` in register `$s6` and not the true unsigned value of `0xFFFFFFFF`. I am confused on how to represent the unsigned value of `0xFFFFFFFF` into the `$s6` register. I am running my code on a ci20 machine not a simulator. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's literally the same value, what's the problem?

Comment: @harold I guess my confusion is I have to error check if the value goes over what can be represented in a single unsigned 32 bit register. When I try to branch when the value is larger than `0xFFFFFFFF` it never branches since the value is being interpreted as the 2's complement.

Comment: It can never take that branch anyway (if you use the unsigned comparisons you can get the predicate correct, but it will be useless), it's impossible to have a value in a register that's larger than the largest value a register can hold, for obvious reasons. If you want to test for overflow, you have to use different techniques.

Comment: @harold Thank you for your responses. I will look more into using a different technique to do my error checking.

Comment: It can't ever branch... because it cannot ever be larger.  It will simply wrap around.